# exclude some characters from being able to write them in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, ascii

good evening,

try to exclude some characters from being able to write them in textbox,
i wrote this code ,its worked

```
private void N_Text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (N_Text.Text.Contains("<") || N_Text.Text.Contains(">") || N_Text.Text.Contains(@"\")
            || N_Text.Text.Contains("/") || N_Text.Text.Contains(";") || N_Text.Text.Contains(":")
            || N_Text.Text.Contains(",") || N_Text.Text.Contains("*") || N_Text.Text.Contains("?")
            || N_Text.Text.Contains("=") || N_Text.Text.Contains("|") || N_Text.Text.Contains("`")
            || N_Text.Text.Contains("\""))
        {
            N_Text.Clear();
        }
    }
```

but is there a better way (short way) for example regex ?

how to delete only characters from textbox, because `.Clear();` clear all text ??

Thanks.

Comment: (not a wpf dev...) Isn't there an OnCharacterReceived event that allows skipping an individual keypress? You'd still need to deal with Paste somehow of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009284/using-regex-to-replace-invalid-characters).
It is possible to do with `Regex.Replace`.

Code example taken from linked issue. I add test input string and use symbols from your example for regular expression pattern:

```
string input = "\"\"   Here<<  is my  >> very \\ lovely // string, where ::: I** wish? to === replace || unliked `` chars \"\" ";       
string pattern = "[<>\\/;:,*?=|`\"]"; // Your unliked chars and symbols
string replacement = string.Empty; // Simply replace to nothing
        
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
// Here would be "   Here  is my   very  lovely  string where  I wish to  replace  unliked  chars"
```

Additionally there provided second Regex replacement to remove several whitespaces in a row. I add only Trim to clear spaces at start and end of an input string:

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\s+", " ").Trim(' ')
// Here would be "Here is my very lovely string where I wish to replace unliked chars"
```

So final adaptation to your example with both replacements may be like this:

```
private void N_Text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   N_Text.Text = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(N_Text.Text, "[<>\\/;:,*?=|`\"]", string.Empty), @"\s+", " ").Trim(' ');    
}
```

Also you can create an Extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ReplaceSymbols(this string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(input, "[<>\\/;:,*?=|`\"]", string.Empty), @"\s+", " ").Trim(' ');
    }
        
    // Or in lambda style       
    // public static string ReplaceSymbols(this string input) => Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(input, "[<>\\/;:,*?=|`\"]", string.Empty), @"\s+", " ").Trim(' ');
}
```

And simply call it:

```
private void N_Text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   N_Text.Text = N_Text.Text.ReplaceSymbols();    
}
```

Be sure you don't forget add reference to `System.Text.RegularExpressions` and take care about double backslashes in a row.